# How to get rid of extra flour on homemade pizza dough and tortillas

Tags: dough, pizza, tortilla

I make my own pizza dough and I just made my own tortillas for the first time.  Both are great, my family and friends like them.

However in both cases I roll them out on a floured cloth and they all wind up still having flour on them at the time of baking or cooking. I blow them off but there is still flour on them after cooking.

Am I using to much flour?

OR should I just spray them with a little water mist?

Comment: Don't spray pizza with water mist! You'll make it soggy. How much flour are we talking here, can you send a pic? Why are you using a cloth instead of a smooth surface?

Comment: A little flour on a pizza can stop it sticking, and reduce the amount of sauce that soaks in if the sauce is a bit wet. So it's not necessarily a bad thing

Comment: What style of pizza?  A well-made Neapolitan pizza dough will need a but of extra flour, but should not be rolled.

Comment: Flour or corn tortillas? Instant masa or home nixtamilized and ground corn? If I'm rolling flour or instant masa tortillas, I'll flour the roller and press the tortilla between waxed paper. Except for a little touch up, no dry flour ever touches the tortilla. Also, they make nice presses for the 5" corn variety. Under $20. I made ny own out of Maple for cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Although they are generally advertised as being for clearing one’s bench of flour, I’ve seen bakers use a flour brush of this sort to remove excess flour from scones etc. [image: long, narrow and soft beech wood and bristle brush]

Comment: Shop brush https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Shop+brush&t=ffsb&ia=products would likely work too, and easy to find.

Answer (score 3):

All around the world, wherever flatbread is stretched or rolled, there seems to be that lovely move at the end of the process, where the sheet is thrown from hand to hand. Anything from the simple 'pat-a-cake' back-and-forth after rolling roti, to the theatrical spinning after stretching Italian-American pizzas. I believe there are two main reasons for it: first, to settle the dough, to let it find its shape without crushing it, and second, to dispose of excess flour.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the amount of excess flour on the surface of pizza and flour tortillas, you can do a few different things:

- Roll out your dough on a non-porous surface that is lightly floured, such as a counter top or large, smooth cutting board - small holes in fabric (or some heavily scratched cutting boards) will cause the dough to push into them and stick, requiring a lot of extra flour.
- Add small amounts of flour as you go to keep your dough from sticking to the surface you are rolling on and your rolling pin
- Let your dough rest in the fridge for a half hour or more (covered with plastic wrap) to become less sticky and more firm, requiring less flour to roll out
- Shake, spin, brush, or pat the rolled out dough to remove any flour which is not stuck to the surface
- Frequently flip you dough as you roll it out
- For flour tortillas, you can try rolling them out sandwiched between sheets of plastic wrap to drastically cut down the amount of flour needed
- For pizzas, you can also stretch the dough by hand which should result in less surface flour